# Is there a way to drop a row, change file, drop next row, change file, and so on using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So this is kinda on the crazy side of problems so I apologize in advance.... What I am trying to accomplish is the ability to read the oldest date from a CSV File, Compare it to today's date, and if the difference between the two is equal to or greater than 55, it will delete rows using Pandas until the condition is met.

I have tried a few different ways through using `df.drop()` however, the closest I have come to getting it is as follows in the code.

Also, here is the numbers from the testFile.csv I am using. (Everything in CSV File is made of strings)

```
2019-05-01 | 14

2019-05-02 | 16

2019-05-03 | 2

2019-05-04 | 3

2019-05-05 | 3

2019-05-06 | 6

2019-05-07 | 14

2019-05-08 | 8

2019-05-09 | 5

2019-05-10 | 1

2019-05-11 | 5

2019-05-12 | 4

2019-05-13 | 1

2019-05-14 | 2

2019-05-15 | 3

2019-05-16 | 8

2019-05-17 | 2

2019-05-18 | 3

2019-05-19 | 4

2019-05-20 | 4
```

```
import datetime, time
import pandas as pd
GLOBAL_PATH = r'C:\Users\DArthur\Documents'
pattern = '%Y-%m-%d'  # CSV Pattern
el_pattern = '%m/%d/%Y:00:00:00'  # Required Pattern by Splunk for search_query, used for TimeStamp


def remove_old_data(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(GLOBAL_PATH + csv_file, sep=',', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df.index[0])).dt.days  # Calculate the date difference
    print(s[0], type(s[0]), type(s))  # Result -- 57 <class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
    df[s.le(55)]#.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get_last_date('/testFile.csv')
    remove_old_data('/testFile.csv')
```

Since the CSV File's oldest date is 57 days from today, the first two rows should be removed from the file. Thus when the file is opened after the program is run its first row starts with 2019-05-03 | 2.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use:

```
s=(pd.to_datetime('today')-pd.to_datetime(df.date)).dt.days
df[s.le(40)]#.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(file,index=False)
```

---

```
          date  count
3   2019-05-04       3
4   2019-05-05       3
5   2019-05-06       6
6   2019-05-07      14
7   2019-05-08       8
8   2019-05-09       5
9   2019-05-10       1
10  2019-05-11       5
11  2019-05-12       4
12  2019-05-13       1
13  2019-05-14       2
14  2019-05-15       3
15  2019-05-16       8
16  2019-05-17       2
17  2019-05-18       3
18  2019-05-19       4
19  2019-05-20       4
```

Comment: @DenDay when you import the file `df=pd.read_csv(file,sep='|',header=None)` it defaults the headers as `0,1,..`  so, instead of `date` , use that `0`.

Comment: I am getting a TimeStamp error. Did I set this up right? ```s = (pd.to_datetime('today')[0] - pd.to_datetime(data_frame[0]).dt[0]).dt[0]
        data_frame.loc[s[s.le(40)].index]```

Comment: @DenDay try `s = (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(data_frame[0])).dt.days` and 
`data_frame[s.le(40)] `

Comment: I have edited the code above to showcase what you taught me and what I got to work so far. I am still working on the second part. I noticed that you edited your code to read ```df[s.le(40)]#.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(file,index=False)``` Can you explain please?

Comment: @DenDay `df[s.le(40)]` is just more succinct , the earlier solution would also work. `s.le(40)` checks which of the series elements is less than equal to (`le()`) 40 and returns True or False. We use it as a boolean mask and use it on the dataframe which filters out the false and returns only the true

Comment: so I've edited to code to force a Series to get boolean, but now when the code runes I get ```Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match``` Is this because of me forcing the Series?

Comment: @DenDay i didnt get you unfortunately.

Comment: apologies, was sidetracked by another project... I have changed the code to the closest current working state however I still get an error. `pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match` This error is coming up pointing to the line `df[s.le(55)]`. I've looked into Series and DataFrames for pandas but still can't find out why the error. The logic seems to just escape me and I feel horrible about it....